# undefined after message passing in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a big problem here.after that my script will be finished i hope :p

I can post script if nessessary.

basically this is what i have been doing.

1. go to some webpage and grab links through content.js
2. pass those links as a array to background.js
3. background.js checks websql database of pre-defined links table and stores in an array.
4. find intersection of two arrays in background.js
5. send the interected array back to content.js
6. content.js will highlight those links with background color.. but this is not happening until i reload the webpage..

I'm not gettting interected array at the first attempt. because of delay.

what should i do now ? :( :'(  Pleasepleaesplease helppppppp.

Comment: I also had to use setTimeout for my intersect function to work properly. database query takes time to result db_links 

a_links are the grabbed links from webpage

Here are some codes as a clue

setTimeout(function(){

found_links = intersect(a_links,db_links);
},1000);

 

sendResponse({backgroundMsg:found_links[2]}); //testing with string instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear with out the code, but from what I understoold, I assume that you are using an ajax call to get the details from database and by the time the result reaches client side, the next function which need the data from database is completed. If this is the case, I would suggest using messaging for the purpose. You can send a message from the extension, to the client side, once the data is received there. On receiving the message the data can be processed, which should probably solve your issue.